# Loop / Iterate over pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, for-loop

I'm new to python, using for loop to iterate csv file,
csv file is given below.

[image]

So I want for sentences:

Launch Flipkart https://www.flipkart.com: (0,6) will be Launch

Enter Email xyz@gmail.com               : (0,5) will be Enter

Below is the code I've used.

```
df=pd.read_csv("File_name.csv")
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in range(0,len(df['SENTENCE'])):
    l1.append(df['SENTENCE'][i])
    l2.append({"entities":[(0,len(df['SENTENCE'][i]),df['Operation'][i])]})
    l2.append({"entities":[(0,len(df['SENTENCE'][i]),df['Argument'][i])]})

TRAIN_DATA=list(zip(l1,l2))
TRAIN_DATA
```

I am facing issue in line no 6 i.e:

```
l2.append({"entities":[(0,len(df['SENTENCE'][i]),df['Operation'][i])]})
```

As `df[SENTENCE'][i]` should be replaced with a variable but couldn't figure out how to create a variable so that I'll get optimal result.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Please add an expected output to your question.

Comment: [('Launch', 'Operation'), ('https://www.flipkart.com', 'Argument')]

Answer (score 0):

To get the first word from each sentence (Operation):

`df2.SENTENCE.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])`

To get the last word from each sentence (Argument):

`df2.SENTENCE.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1])`

Comment: Actually I'm training the data and I want the Launch to be identified as Operation,         Launch Flipkart https://www.flipkart.com for this sentence I want (0,6) value to be operation.

Comment: So you want to extract 'launch' from the sentence? a.k.a. the first word? Then simply use: `df.SENTENCE.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])`

Comment: I have more than 100 sentences in the csv file, so I want for every sentences operations to be identified.

Comment: But some sentences have operations in between.

Comment: @Paul note that instead of apply lambda you can do `df.SENTENCE.str.split(" ").str[0]` here

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestions. I want to extract 'launch' from the sentence, it is first word but I have more than 100 sentences in the csv file but some sentences have operations in between, it's not always the first word.

Comment: @mcsoini Indeed you are right

Comment: @Mike How would you logically extract it? Search a list of possible operations? Same goes for the Argument, if it is not standard the last word, what logic would you use? If it requires a higher level of intelligence, you need to use AI/ML to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the response, one more thing what if Operation is somewhere in between the sentence.

Comment: Then you would need to know where it is, either by searching for a finite list of possible operations (f.e. [Launch, Enter]), or by passing an extra argument on what location the word is located (f.e. 3, for the 4th word in the sentence)

Comment: @Paul thanks for all the help, issue has been resolved.